# Highcharts performance - why is Chart.redraw called twice when adding a point?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Looking at the [standard Highstock dynamic update demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/dynamic-update/) in Chrome DevTools' Timeline panel, I noticed something (apparently) strange: for every call to `Series#addPoint`, Highstock seemingly calls `Chart#redraw` *twice*, and both times it goes all the way down to `Series#render`, so the time spent in the `redraw` calls is not trivial (exact numbers at the end).

See the flame chart below for a visual representation of the stack. The important methods are highlighted in red. The stack goes from top-to-bottom and left-to-right, i.e.,functions at the top call those below them, and time flows from left to right.

[image: Highcharts double redraw flame chart]

The exact time spent in the important methods is as follows (this is total time, including all methods called from the method):

- 47 ms taken by `addPoint`, of which

  - 45 ms taken by the 1st call to `Chart#redraw`, of which

    - 40 ms taken by the 1st call to `Series#redraw`, of which

      - 2.5 ms taken by the 1st call to `Series#render` and
      - **24 ms** taken by the 2nd call to `Chart#redraw`, of which

        - 13 ms taken by the 2nd call to `Series#redraw`, of which

          - 7 ms taken by the 2nd call to `Series#render`

Considering that 32 ms is all I have if I want an acceptable rendering rate of 30 fps, that 24 ms for the second `Chart#redraw` really bothers me. So my question is: does Highcharts really need that second `redraw`, or is it duplicating work? If it is not, why is the double call needed?

Comment: Seems to be related to a reported issue: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2266 If so, you could try setting redraw parameter to false, as suggested in the issue.

Comment: @KacperMadej if I set it to false, the chart will never update, right? And if I do call `Chart#redraw` myself, we're back to the same problem, i.e., `redraw` recursively calls itself again: http://jsfiddle.net/vickychijwani/52jo1m90/2/. Unless I misunderstood your suggestion?

Comment: Sorry to hear that - it was suggested in the issue that this might help, however it is not always working. Issue is open and there is no better workaround suggested for now.

Comment: Ive seen this exact same behavior in Highcharts JS v5.0.0 (2016-09-29)